# Returning a generic container without templating the class

Tags: c++, templates, containers

Consider this snippet:

```
template< typename A, typename B >
struct A
{
public:
    typedef std::map< A, B > map;
};


class B
{
public:
    B(const ??map) : _map(map) {}
    const ??map getMap();
private:
        ??map _map;
};


int main(){
    A<int, int>::map myMap;
    B b(myMap); ???
    ..
    ..
    A<int, int>::map = b.getMap(); ???
}
```

What I want to do is:

1. Injecting a generic map into B
2. Class B should not be a template class
3. Get from B the generic map back

I don't know how this can be done.
Somehow the templated map should be wrapped and the getMap method of B should return a proxy object from which the actual map can be pulled out(with a cast?).

I'm afraid of having many classes to be templated, just because one member is generic and so passing down the template paramter the entire hierarchy down.

Comment: What kind of problem you're trying to solve by using such design?

Comment: @Nawaz +1 for bringing up [the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: depending on what you want to do with the map, you can 'hide' it behind an interface, then provide an implementation of the intrface using whatever map you want

Comment: I cannot imagine how this works; I always end up with concrete maps returning back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly what you are looking for are *traits classes*. Andrei Alexandrescu termed them the "[else-if-then of types](http://erdani.com/publications/traits.html)".

A traits class simply carries information (like types) and algorithms (like, say, "advance"). You first define the general information, which will apply to any type `T`, and then you specialize the traits class for specific types `U` which grant the special behavior.

```
In your case (an example more complex than it needs to be):

#include<iostream>
#include<map>

template<typename T>
struct container_traits {
  using container_t = std::map<int, int>;
};

class Foo {
 public:  
  using key_type = typename container_traits<Foo>::container_t::key_type;
  using mapped_type = typename container_traits<Foo>::container_t::mapped_type;
  using size_type = typename container_traits<Foo>::container_t::size_type;

  Foo() { }

  size_type insert(key_type key, mapped_type val) {
    m_container.insert(std::make_pair(key, val));
    return m_container.size();
  }

 private:
  container_traits<Foo>::container_t m_container;
};

int main() {
  Foo f;
  std::cout<<f.insert(5, 4)<<std::endl;
}
```

Notice what is happening: the traits class `container_traits` class defines that "for every type `T`, there will be a type called `container_t`, which---in general--is a `map<int, int>`.

If you then defined a type `Bar` which required a `map<string, string>` as the container, you could simply redefine the traits class as:

```
template<>
struct container_traits<Bar> {
 using container_t = std::map<string, string>;
};
```

Then, whenever you call `container_traits<Bar>::container_t`, you will be retrieving the correct map.

My explanation of traits classes cannot do justice to the actual article which I linked: read it. It is a very simple concept, but it is very powerful. Modern C++ design (in the context of generic programming) relies heavily on traits classes (as does the Standard Library).